# Openstreetmap not correctly displaying

Tags: javascript, angular, openlayers, openstreetmap

I tried to bind the openstreetmap layer to my angular2/4 application. I used this simple example:

```
  <script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>   <script
 type="text/javascript"
 src="http://www.openstreetmap.org/openlayers/OpenStreetMap.js"></script>
```

**apiOpenLayer.service.ts**
    import { Injectable, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Response, Http, Headers, RequestMethod, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
    declare var OpenLayers: any;

```
declare var $: any;
declare OpenLayers: any;

@Injectable()
export class APIOpenLayer {
    public map: any;


    init() {
        this.map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");
        var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
        var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
        var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
        var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(13.41,52.52).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);
        var zoom           = 15; 

        this.map.addLayer(mapnik);
        this.map.setCenter(position, zoom );
      }     

}
```

This service I am calling in the compoent

**map.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {APIOpenLayer} from '../../../services/apiOpenLayer.service';
declare var OpenLayers:any;
@Component({
  selector: 'search',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './map.component.html'
})

export class SearchComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
constructor(public apiMapService:APIOpenLayer){}
ngAfterViewInit(){
this.apiMapService.init();
}
}
```

I can see the container but not the map within the container like this:

[image]

The map is added within a tab. Maybe this could be the problem?

Comment: map looks fine to me

Comment: it's a joke - why post a blank image?

Comment: The map is within a tab. Maybe this could be the problem?

Comment: Hi @moglimogli , I'm facing the same issue right now. did you find a solution?